# how to set up an ESP8266 as a webserver

Tags: esp8266, web-server, networking

I would like to set up an esp8266, connected arduino as a webserver, specifically, one that has its own IP, and is stand alone, not connected to other networks, and offers its sensor info as the contents of its internal webpage. what is this called?

I see numerous examples for connecting the esp8266 to another network, but that is not what I want to do. I want the esp8266 to read its sensors, and write a webpage, but have other devices connect to it.

Comment: https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/WiFiAccessPoint/WiFiAccessPoint.ino

Comment: The keyword to search for is "SOFTAP".

Comment: the ESP8266 has to act as a `wifi access point` .... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=esp8266+wifi+access+point&ia=web